# Has anybody been to UX London?

Tags: discussion, conference

http://2012.uxlondon.com/

Is it any good?

I just attended the NNG Usability Week in SF but was a bit disappointed, most of the content was a bit trivial IMO.

Comment: hey Phil! Have not been but would hope that the content is more advanced that what we received.

Comment: Let me know if you (or anyone else around!) makes the trip out and we'll make sure you have .SE stuff. UX may even have a site design and specific UX.se swag by then. Sorry to hear NNg wasn't great.

Comment: Katey: Ok, will do. / colmcq: Welcome back :)

Comment: i think you should use the jesus pic as the avatar P

Comment: haha, the UX jebuz! :P

Comment: I would love to go, but I would have to pay the grand out of my own pocket, and I can't afford it. :(

Comment: dude, this one might be worth it; the networking opps are amazing. There are not many folks in UX and its srsly good to get your name known.

Comment: ho hum - some great speakers. Lot of money though. Quandry!

Comment: you can save up, that's what I did for NNgroup

Comment: @KateyΨ - I've gone and done it - I bagged an early bird ticket, so will be going to UX London in April. Once I get over the cost I will be veeerrry excited! :-)

Comment: @Roger: Nice :) If I can convince my boss I'll be there too

Comment: @everyone srsly considering it too

Comment: @RogerAttrill awesome! When it gets closer to, I will send a package to you (or your hotel). I visited London in May, and while I had a great time BUT pack a heavier coat than you think you are going to need, I froze the whole time I was there.

Comment: @KateyΨ Great, thanks. I'm actually only an hour's drive from London anyway - but totally agree about the weather here - it's about as predictable as an unpredictable thing :-)

Comment: Hahaha yes, agreed. The wind really surprised me - NYC can get cold and windy but it really was substantively different in London.

Comment: Ok, got my ticket. See you there hopefully!

Comment: @KateyHW This event is coming up in a couple of weeks. Are you still planning to send something over?

Answer (score 4):

So here I am at UX London 2012. Is it any good? Yehuh! Apart form the lack of wifi at the venue which has not gone unmentioned by a single person here. It should be working - it's just broken, and will probably be fixed the day after we leave. To be honest - maybe it wasn't a bad thing to have people paying attention rather than tweeting every damn word. For those interested - the twitter hashtag for this event is just (oh jeez - I'm borrowing someone's MacBook Air - where's the hash on this thing. Alt-3 in the UK - thank you!) #UXLondon

Today was the first and only day of talks, the next two consisting of workshops. So far we had Bill Buxton, Anders Ramsay, Luke Wroblewski, Kristina Halvorson, Jared Spool, Bill Derouchey, Jon Kolko and a couple of others giving amazing, engaging and inspiring talks that have left me on a real high buzz. I'm hoping that I can compartmentalise all this input in my sleep, because honestly, theres so much I found interesting that I don't think I want to try and distill notes - because I can almost guarantee nearly everything that was said today might be useful at some point in the future - if not the second I get back to work.

Fortunately others have done some of that notetaking already - like Luke Wroblewski who has published his notes on his website:

Harry Brignull: [From Print to iPad](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1542)

Jon Kolko: [Social Entrepreneurship](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1544)

Bill Derouchey: [Design with an Opinion](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1543)

Jared Spool: [Mobile & UX A Perfect Storm](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1541)

Anders Ramsay: [Agile UX Rugby](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1540)

Kristina Halvorson: [Content Strategy Roadmap](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1539)

Bill Buxton: [Long Nose of Innovation](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1538)

Luke Wroblewski's own talk was much along the lines of the chapter on organising mobile content from his book Mobile First - stressing the importance of considering content first and navigation second.

In the bar after the first day, most of the speakers were there - I found myself talking to Luke Wroblewski briefly about the pros and cons of various Q/A forums for UX topics - i.e. like UX.SE and Quora. I'd like to have explored this more but he had to disappear to the UX book club event that was in the same venue.

I had a chat with Stephen Anderson about his workshop tomorrow - the quest for emotional engagement and information visualisation which I'm incredibly excited about as I've always been a proponent of visualisation for conveying ideas, designs, and just about anything to other people.

If the next two days are as inspiring as today I'm going to leave here very happy to recommend this event to others who may be unsure whether it's worth considering next year.

Comment: No, don't recommend it to others! It's hard enough for *us* to find tickets for it, we don't need any more competition for places! ;)

Comment: so jealous..........

Answer (score 0):

UX London was awesome. It's inspired me (again) and given me so much confidence that I'm doing all the right things as a UX professional.